# I don't think my duplicate vote should have been that effective

Tags: bug, dupehammer

I cast the second close vote on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080978/adding-image-to-html-using-flask) question after a gold badge user cast the first one.

- Said gold badge user should have been hammering the question, as they have a gold badge, yet that did not happen.
- Question was closed instantly when my vote was cast, yet no mention of the hammering is present, as usual when dupe hammering.

This leaves the question in a strange state with only two duplicate vote casters.

Am I seeing things? Is the new year having a strange effect on SO? Did the second vote trigger the usual dupe hammering, that for some reason would have been stalled? Is this only coincidental, and there was some delay in the hammering?

Comment: I know for a fact that davidism has a gold badge in Python and has used that to hammer dupes before.  I'm not seeing any time delta between when you two closed the question (because the timeline page doesn't provide that), but it *feels* like a race condition in the UI in which there *was* a binding vote but it was assumed to be the last vote registered.

Comment: we have a question closed with 6 votes also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080115/comparing-a-matrix-cell-to-null-in-c .. something bad is coming ..

Comment: [Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54080978/revisions) and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54080978/timeline) for ease of clicking.

Comment: Smells like race conditions.

Comment: There were a few glitches earlier today, such that even ♦-moderators had some issues closing or deleting questions with a single vote. Blame race conditions.

Comment: How many new contenders are in the race, exactly....?